# Do something with every X item in while loop

Tags: php, while-loop

```
$i = 0;

while ($have_something) {

    if($i == 0 || $i == 3 || $i == 6 || $i == 9) {
        $color = 'black';
    }
    else {
        $color = 'white';
    }
    $i++;
}
```

Problem occurs with this code when count of items in `while` loop is dynamic and changes regulary, also when it could have hundreds of items which means that `if` statement would be very long.

How to overcome this problem and *"automate"* it so that something happens with every **X** item and something else for the rest without hardcoding `$i` count?

Comment: is this, by chance, anything to do with colouring table rows or similar?

Comment: @RamRaider Nope, just bunch of thumbnails of articles. Im trying to make it a bit less boring by changing something for every X element. Could `%` operator be used like this: 1. is black, 2. and 3. white, 4. black, 5. and 6. and 7. and 8. white, 9. black and then it repeats from second one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the modulus operator `%`:

```
$i = 0;

while ($have_something) {

    if($i % 3 == 0 ) {
        $color = 'black';
    }
    else {
        $color = 'white';
    }
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: or, slightly neater perhaps `$color=( $i % 3 == 0 ) ? 'black' : 'white';`

Comment: sure ... depends on the amount of actual code, that is executed. but i think, one better gets the gist of this answer using an `if`.

Comment: @RamRaider less is not always more.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to using php to generate what I assume will be a class or inline color definition would be purely in css by using the `nth-of-type(3n)` style selector.

```
<style>
    #rep{ width:80%; float:none; margin:5rem auto; box-sizing:border-box; padding:1rem; }
    #rep div{ width:100%; float:none; margin:0.1rem auto; box-sixing:border-box; border:1px solid black; }
    #rep div:nth-of-type(2n){ background:whitesmoke; }
    #rep div:nth-of-type(3n){ background:gray; }
    #rep div:nth-of-type(4n){ background: #f0ffff; }
    #rep div:nth-of-type(5n){ background: #f0fff0; }
    #rep div:nth-of-type(6n){ background: #e0ffff; }
    #rep div:nth-of-type(7n){ background: #f0f8ff; }
    #rep div:nth-of-type(8n){ background: #e6e6fa; }
    #rep div:nth-of-type(9n){ background: #b0e0e6; }
</style>

echo "<div id='rep'>";
for( $i=0; $i < 30; $i++ ) echo "<div>$i</div>";
echo "</div>";
```

Anyway, just a thought!

or, a better css selector is `nth-child` perhaps
`#rep div:nth-child(3n){background:black;`}

if you are interested in this technique this would be a [handy guide](http://flanneljesus.github.io/web%20design/2014-09-22/nth-child-trick/) possibly